# local import paths with WSGI don't work for me

Tags: mod-wsgi, wsgi

I wrote a WSGI script that depends on importing files in the same directory.  Does WSGI use paths differently?  Could my (mod_wsgi apachae) server be insane?

Answer (score 0):

The current working directory for a WSGI server could be anything and for different WSGI servers could be different. Further, command line Python interpreter will by default look in the current working directory where as for an embedded system it will not.

End result is that relying on being able to import modules from the same directory as a WSGI script file is not portable. You will need to set sys.path or PYTHONPATH as appropriate for the WSGI server being used to ensure that modules from a specific location can be imported. You cannot rely on a default of looking in the current working directory as may occur for command line Python.

Comment: Ah, so it is more portable to write in those files as classes in the main script!